# cmake finds package, but does not add to include path

Tags: cmake, include-path

I am trying to compile (on FreeBSD, if that matters) a program that uses cmake. The `CMakeLists.txt` contains the lines

```
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} ${OPENGL32_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

and cmake does not report any errors, but when I run `make` afterwards, I get

```
[…]
/usr/bin/c++  -fopenmp -I/path/build -o CMakeFiles/scriptbots.dir/GLView.cpp.o -c /path/GLView.cpp
[…]
In file included from /path/GLView.cpp:2:
/path/GLView.cpp:10:21: error: GL/glut.h: No such file or directory
[…]
```

GL/glut.h exists in `/usr/local/include`, which is not given as `-I` argument to `/usr/bin/c++`.

Compiling works when I explicitly add `-I/usr/local/include` to `CMakeFiles/scriptbots.dir/flags.make`. What do I need to change to make the project compile without manually changing the flags file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per its documentation, `FindGLUT` sets variable `GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR`, not `GLUT_INCLUDE_DIRS`. Change this in your CMakeList and it should work.